# How to get Multiline response in POP3

Tags: java, sockets, pop3

```
    try{
        smtpSocket= new Socket("pop.rediffmail.com",110);
        os=new DataOutputStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream());
        is=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(smtpSocket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.print("Inbox List": \n");
        os.writeBytes("list\r\n");
        System.out.println(is.readLine());
```

The Program not show all the list of the mail. How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Read [RFC 1939](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939), which defines the POP3 protocol.  In particular, read [section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939#section-3), which tells you how to read multi-line responses:

> Responses to certain commands are multi-line.  In these cases, which
> are clearly indicated below, after sending the first line of the
> response and a CRLF, any additional lines are sent, each terminated
> by a CRLF pair.  When all lines of the response have been sent, a
> final line is sent, consisting of a termination octet (decimal code
> 046, ".") and a CRLF pair.  If any line of the multi-line response
> begins with the termination octet, the line is "byte-stuffed" by
> pre-pending the termination octet to that line of the response.
> Hence a multi-line response is terminated with the five octets
> "CRLF.CRLF".  When examining a multi-line response, the client checks
> to see if the line begins with the termination octet.  If so and if
> octets other than CRLF follow, the first octet of the line (the
> termination octet) is stripped away.  If so and if CRLF immediately
> follows the termination character, then the response from the POP
> server is ended and the line containing ".CRLF" is not considered
> part of the multi-line response.

For example:

```
try{
    smtpSocket= new Socket("pop.rediffmail.com",110);
    os=new DataOutputStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream());
    is=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(smtpSocket.getInputStream()));
    string line = is.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    if (line.startsWith("+OK")){
        System.out.println("Inbox List:");
        os.writeBytes("list\r\n");
        line = is.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        if (line.startsWith("+OK")){
            do {
                line = is.readLine();
                if (line == ".") break;
                if (line.startsWith("."))
                    line = line.substring(1);
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            while (true);
        } 
    }
```